# SQLAlchemy one-to-one, store foreign key in each table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a relationship that is one to one between cage codes and duns numbers.

I have set up my relationship that looks like, where I store a ForeignKey on each of the respective tables.

```
class Cage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimCage'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cage = Column(String(8), unique=True, nullable=False)
    duns_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('DimDuns.id'))

    duns = relationship('Duns', uselist=False, back_populates='cage')


class Duns(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimDuns'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    duns = Column(String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
    dunsInt = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    cage_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('DimCage.id'))

    cage = relationship('Cage', uselist=False, back_populates='duns')
```

When I create the tables I get the below error, how to do I set up my foreign keys so I can keep a reference on both tables?

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'DimCage' and 'DimDuns'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.

And During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Cage.duns - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need to store one foreign key for a one-to-one relationship.
See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

You shouldn't lose any data access this way. If you remove the `duns_id` column from `Cage`, you now access the id by `cage.duns.id` instead of `cage.duns_id`.

Comment: That is how I would normally do it, i didn't know if people put fk in both tables. The examples does show a parent <-> child, and this is more like a brother <-> brother relationship.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the child  **primary key as a foreign key** to the parent.

For a design perspective, it is not a bad choice to use foreign keys as primary keys in One-to-One relationships.

```
class Cage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimCage'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cage = Column(String(8), unique=True, nullable=False)


class Duns(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimDuns'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Cage.id) primary_key=True)
    
    duns = Column(String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
    dunsInt = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)

    cage = relationship('Cage', uselist=False, backref='duns')
```

Now both cage and duns have the same id. So:

```
session.add(Cage(id=1, duns=Duns(duns='Duns', dunsInt=10)))
sesion.commit()
```

---

```
id = 1

cage = select(Cage).where(Cage.id == id)

duns = select(Duns).where(Duns.id == cage.id)

assert cage.id == duns.id
```

Please note that the child cannot exist without the parent.

If the parent is going to be deleted then the child must be deleted first, unless you configure some `cascade` option.