# OneToOne Relationship with a foreign key on both sides

Tags: sqlalchemy

How can I define a OneToOne-relationship between two tables and have a foreign key on both sides? I know that it is redundant.

```
class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'A'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), unique=True, nullable=False)
  b = relationship("B", uselist=False, back_populates="a")

class B(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'B'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'), unique=True)
  a = relationship("A", uselist=False, back_populates="b")
```

This results into an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ...
```

I found this duplicate to my question: [SQLAlchemy one-to-one, store foreign key in each table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691341/sqlalchemy-one-to-one-store-foreign-key-in-each-table) but the accepted answer is not an answer to the question. I only tells that normaly only one key is needed.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: I decided to put my foreign key into my Table A, cause I need nullable=false constraint. On the other side, in table B I need a unique(with null) contraint. My idea was to use a join-tabel, but I think with foreign keys on both side, it would work too.